# Issue in installing SSL Certificate to Apache Linux 2 Lightsail instance

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, aws, bitnami

I have already installed Certbot. I have already addded a Virtual host with Servername : mywebsite.com and Server Alias etc.

Currently, it has saved the httpd-vhosts.conf with these files. httpd-vhosts.conf.save. httpd-vhosts.conf.save1 and httpd-vhosts.conf.save2 as shown in
the image.  [image: Installing SSL]

what should be the next step?